# The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 2 error

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, tensor, attention-model

i trying to visualization attention in a model of image captioning, but got error that saying that the size of tensor a must match the size of tensor b.

```
<ipython-input-50-b849fcdd95cf> in generate_caption(autoencoder, encoder, decoder, image_path, image_transform, field, max_len, device, image_shape, beam_size)
     47 
     48 
---> 49             alpha = decoder.attention(image_features, h_state)
     50 
     51             alpha = alpha.view(-1, 14, 14)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-19-643e95087487> in forward(self, features, h_state)
     17         """
     18         h_state = h_state.unsqueeze(1) # [batch_size, 1, dec_hidden_size]
---> 19         score = F.elu(self.W1(features) + self.W2(h_state)) # [batch_size, num_pixels, hidden_size]
     20         attention_weights = F.softmax(self.V(score), dim=1) # [batch_size, num_pixels, 1]
     21         context_vector = attention_weights * features # [batch_size, num_pixels, enc_hidden_size]
```

> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor
> b (3) at non-singleton dimension 2

And it's the code i used to generate the attention

```
def generate_caption(autoencoder, encoder, decoder, image_path, image_transform, field, max_len, device, image_shape=(256, 256), beam_size=3):
assert callable(image_transform)

# Load the image
image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
image = image_transform(image.resize(image_shape))
image = image.unsqueeze(0)

autoencoder.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    image = image.to(device)
        
    k = beam_size

    # Top k previous token indices at each step
    topk_prev_tokens = torch.LongTensor([[field.vocab.stoi[field.init_token]]] * k).to(device)  # [k, 1]

    # Top k sequences
    topk_sequences = topk_prev_tokens  # [k, 1]

    # Top k sequences' logps
    topk_logps = torch.zeros(k, 1).to(device)  # [k, 1]

    # (k, 1, enc_image_size, enc_image_size)
    seqs_alpha = torch.ones(k, 1, 14, 14).to(device)

    # Complete sequences and logps
    complete_sequences, complete_seqs_alpha, complete_sequence_logps = [], [], []

    # Encoding
    image_features = encoder(image) # [1, 14, 14, hidden_size]
    image_features = image_features.view(1, -1, encoder.hidden_size) # [1, num_pixels, enc_hidden_size]
    image_features = image_features.expand(k, -1, -1) # [k, num_pixels, enc_hidden_size]

    # Init hidden and memory states
    mean_image_features = image_features.mean(dim=1) # [k, enc_hidden_size]
    h_state, c_state =autoencoder.init_h0(mean_image_features), autoencoder.init_c0(mean_image_features) # [k, dec_hidden_size]
    

    # Decoding
    step = 1
    while True:
        if len(h_state.shape) < 3:
            h_state, c_state = h_state.unsqueeze(0), c_state.unsqueeze(0) # [1, k, dec_hidden_size]

        logit, h_state, c_state, _ = decoder(topk_prev_tokens.squeeze(1), h_state, c_state, image_features)
        

        alpha = decoder.attention(image_features, h_state) 

        alpha = alpha.view(-1, 14, 14)

        # Get scores
        logp = F.log_softmax(logit, dim=1) # [k, vocab_size]

        # Extend
        logp = topk_logps.expand_as(logp) + logp  # [k, vocab_size]

        # At the 1st step, the score is 0
        if step == 1:
            topk_logps, topk_tokens = logp[0].topk(k, 0, True, True)  # [k,]
        else:
            # Unroll and find top logp, and their unrolled indices
            topk_logps, topk_tokens = logp.view(-1).topk(k, 0, True, True)  # [k,]

        # Convert unrolled indices to actual indices of logp
        prev_tokens = topk_tokens // decoder.vocab_size  # [k,]
        next_tokens = topk_tokens % decoder.vocab_size  # [k,]

        # Add new indices to topk_sequences
        topk_sequences = torch.cat((topk_sequences[prev_tokens], next_tokens.unsqueeze(1)), dim=1) # [k, step + 1]
        seqs_alpha = torch.cat([seqs_alpha[prev_tokens], alpha[prev_tokens].unsqueeze(1)], dim=1)  # (s, step+1, enc_image_size, enc_image_size)

        # Get the complete and incomplete sequences
        incomplete_indices = [indice for indice, next_token in enumerate(next_tokens) if next_token != field.vocab.stoi[field.eos_token]]
        complete_indices = list(set(range(len(next_tokens))) - set(incomplete_indices))

        # Set aside complete sequences
        if len(complete_indices) > 0:
            complete_sequences.extend(topk_sequences[complete_indices].tolist())
            complete_seqs_alpha.extend(seqs_alpha[complete_indices].tolist())
            complete_sequence_logps.extend(topk_logps[complete_indices])

        # Reduce beam length accordingly
        k -= len(complete_indices) 

        # Proceed with incomplete sequences
        if k == 0:
            break

        topk_sequences = topk_sequences[incomplete_indices]
        seqs_alpha = seqs_alpha[incomplete_indices]
        h_state = h_state[:, prev_tokens[incomplete_indices], :]
        c_state = c_state[:, prev_tokens[incomplete_indices], :]
        image_features = image_features[prev_tokens[incomplete_indices]]
        topk_logps = topk_logps[incomplete_indices].unsqueeze(1)
        topk_prev_tokens = next_tokens[incomplete_indices].unsqueeze(1)

        # Break if things have been going on too long
        if step > max_len:
            if len(complete_indices) == 0:
                complete_sequences.extend(topk_sequences.tolist())
                complete_sequence_logps.extend(topk_logps[incomplete_indices])
            break

        # Update step
        step += 1

    i = complete_sequence_logps.index(max(complete_sequence_logps))
    sequence = complete_sequences[i]
    alphas = complete_seqs_alpha[i]
    
    caption = ' '.join([field.vocab.itos[token] for token in sequence if token not in 
                           {field.vocab.stoi[field.init_token],
                            field.vocab.stoi[field.eos_token],
                            field.vocab.stoi[field.pad_token]}])
    
return sequence, alphas
```

the error comes from the line `alpha = decoder.attention(image_features, h_state)`. Thanks for your helping

Comment: You need to attach the code of `decoder.attention`. In addition, please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).